# ShadowIntent is null - Robolectric 3.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, robolectric

I have a login fragment. When the user enter his credentials,he clicks the button and then a new activity is started. Here is the code.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

Button loginButton;
EditText etName,etPass;
String login_name;
String login_pass;
private SessionManager session;
TextView forgotPassBtn;

public LoginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    etName = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    etPass = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.user_pass);
    loginButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    login_name = etName.getText().toString();
    login_pass = etName.getText().toString();

    forgotPassBtn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.forgotPass);

    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());

    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Welcome.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            login_name = etName.getText().toString();
            login_pass = etPass.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

            if(login_name.isEmpty() && login_pass.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Username η κωδικός είναι κενό",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                editor.putString("id", "");
                editor.putString("user_name", login_name);
                editor.putString("user_pass", login_pass);
                editor.commit();

                loginUser(login_name, login_pass);
            }
        }
    });
   return v;

}



private void loginUser(final String userName,
                       final String password) {
    /*
    Tag used to cancel the request
    HttpsTrustManager.sssMethod();
    */
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";


    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", "Register Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("success")) {
                    session.setLogin(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(Welcome.newIntent(getActivity()));
                }

                else if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("fail")) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Launch login activity


            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error", "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            //params.put("id","");
            params.put("user_name", userName);
            params.put("user_pass", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
  }

}
```

The new activity starts here

```
 if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("success")) {
                session.setLogin(true);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(Welcome.newIntent(getActivity()));
            }

            else if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("fail")) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
```

The code works fine,as I tested it. But now I want to test it with robolectric. 
So far I have tested the visibility of the views as well as the fragment itself.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,sdk = 21)
public class LoginFragmentTest {
MainActivity activity;
Button loginButton;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    loginButton = getButton(activity,R.id.loginButton);
}

@Test
public void loginFragmentShouldNotBeNull(){
    LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
    startFragment(loginFragment, AppCompatActivity.class);
    assertNotNull(loginFragment);

}

@Test
public void shouldHaveUserNameEntry() throws Exception{
    EditText nameEntry = getEditText(activity,R.id.user_name);
    assertViewIsVisible(nameEntry);
}

@Test
public void shouldHavePasswordEntry() throws Exception{
    EditText passEntry = getEditText(activity,R.id.user_pass);
    assertViewIsVisible(passEntry);

}

@Test
public void shouldHaveLoginButton() throws Exception{
    assertNotNull(loginButton);
    assertViewIsVisible(loginButton);

}
@Test
public void shouldStartNewActivityWhenLoginButtonClicked() throws Exception {
    loginButton.performClick();

    ShadowActivity shadowActivity = shadowOf(activity);

    Intent intent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
    ShadowIntent shadowIntent = shadowOf(intent);
    //assertEquals(shadowIntent.getComponent().getClassName(),Welcome.class.getName());
    }
 }
```

The tests

```
loginFragmentShouldNotBeNull
shouldHaveUserNameEntry
shouldHavePasswordEntry
```

are passed.

However, I get an exception with the

```
shouldHaveLoginButton
```

Here it is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.robolectric.internal.ShadowExtractor.extract(ShadowExtractor.java:5)
at org.robolectric.Shadows.shadowOf(Shadows.java:1112)
at team.football.ael.LoginFragmentTest.shouldStartNewActivityWhenLoginButtonClicked(LoginFragmentTest.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:527)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:265)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:191)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:56)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:157)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed. I changed the shouldStartNewActivityWhenLoginButtonClicked() method to:

```
  public void shouldStartNewActivityWhenLoginButtonClicked() throws Exception {
    loginButton.performClick();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    welcomeActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(Welcome.class).withIntent(intent).create().get();
}
```